# Импорт CSV в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

У меня есть файл csv, разделитель - запятая. Проблема в том что в значениях csv есть поле в котором данные окружены кавычками и между кавычками может попасться запятая.
Типа  так:

```
1,2,3,"какие-то данные, и между ними запятая",5,6,7
```

Как это импортировать?
(Вообще это файл с kaggle соревнования "Титаник" вот там в поле "Name" фамилия вынесена вперёд и отделена запятой от имени)

Короче я не в ту таблицу вставлял, поэтому полей не хватало, запятая не при чём.

Comment: А как вы пытаетесь сделать это в данный момент? ибо запятая внутри кавычек - нормальная практика для csv, всё что находится в кавычках - текст ячейки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Это корректный формат CSV.
Просто при загрузке данных нужно указать что текстовые поля ограничены кавычками.

Загружаете файл как обычно? например так:

```
COPY table_name(fields list)
FROM 'data.csv'
DELIMITER ',' 
QUOTE '"' 
CSV;
```

Ну или можно **QUOTE** не указывать - для формата CSV двойные кавычки и так по умолчанию.

Comment: Там текстовых полей много, а в кавычках только поле Name

Comment: PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C

Comment: ERROR: ОШИБКА:  лишние данные после содержимого последнего столбца
CONTEXT:  COPY char_data_types, строка 2: "1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S"


SQL state: 22P04

Comment: @qwerty1999 отредактируйте свой вопрос, пожалуйста. Укажатие там струтуру таблицы в которую загружаете данные, приведите пример CSV файла. Ну и желательно указать SQL запрос которым пытаетесь импортировать данные.

Comment: оооой, я в другую таблицу пытался вставить хДДД